# column update with other column in mysql on specific row

Tags: mysql

```
id  craeted_date         updated_date
121 1556192726251       1556773299198
35  1556192726254       1556781196570
325 1556192726253       1556781296607
365 1556192726256       1556781346627
398 1556192726258       1556781496675
```

I want to select table  table like below
second row of craeted_date is updated by first row of updated_date
and 3rd row of craeted_date is updated by 2nd row of updated_date
like this

```
id  craeted_date         updated_date
121 1556192726251       1556773299198
35  1556773299198       1556781196570
325 1556781196570       1556781296607
365 1556781296607       1556781346627
398 1556781346627       1556781496675
```

am using below query its update all column 
update user_tbl set craeted_date=updated_date
but  i need to modify  craeted_date second row

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using MySQL 8+, then we can take advantage of the `LAG` analytic function:

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET craeted_date = LAG(updated_date, 1, craeted_date) OVER (ORDER BY craeted_date);
```

On earlier versions of MySQL, the following update join might work:

```
UPDATE yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT craeted_date, updated_date
    FROM (
        SELECT t1.craeted_date,
            COALESCE((SELECT t2.updated_date
             FROM yourTable t2
             WHERE t2.craeted_date < t1.craeted_date
             ORDER BY t2.craeted_date DESC
             LIMIT 1), t1.craeted_date) updated_date
         FROM yourTable t1
    ) t
) t2
    ON t1.craeted_date = t2.craeted_date
SET t1.craeted_date = t2.updated_date;
```

Comment: hi while executing 1st query getting below error Error Code: 1093. You can't specify target table 'table' for update in FROM clause 0.032 sec

Comment: @joe please specify  your mysql version

Comment: Server version: 5.7.24-

Comment: @joe I managed to articulate a solution for MySQL 5.7, see the updated answer.

Comment: am getting below error while executing query SQL Error: Column 'craeted_date' in field list is ambiguous

Comment: @joe I updated my answer so that all fields are unambiguous.